# Receiving audio and video on android over HDMI or USB connection

Tags: java, android, usb, media, hdmi

I am rather new to Android development but I wish to receive audio and video content on my phone from a pc. I am trying to record gameplay on my pc, and do not have the money to buy the hardware recorder, and I can not do screen capture and maintain acceptable fps.

What I had in mind was to send my screen and audio to my phone like a second screen, where my phone will handle the saving process, reducing cpu load on my pc. I don't think android phones can receive hdmi output, but I can do this with the USB via the android adb library "pull" command. However this requires that the file already be saved.

I can't seem to find any other way to do this, can anyone recommend a library I could use?

Comment: take a look at http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2505510 I think it might help you, this guy is sharing his sources.
Sadly it's only for Nvidia, so it can be very specific.

Answer (score 1):

No. USBs are slow. And there is no way to transfer what's on your computer screen to your android device without first recording it on the computer itself and then having to pass through the slow USB device and then slowly writing it to your phone's hard drive. You'll be recording at a solid 0.5fps by then.